# Is it possible to configure router to prioritize "normal" network usage over "torrent" downloads high network usage

Tags: switch, router, lan, isp

I have a typical problem of having a shared connection with many people. 
The connection provided by my ISP is good enough to service many people (50mbs). However, every now and then, when someone starts downloading something, or some system process is performing an update,  i will lose internet connection since that single user/process will use up as much of the bandwidth as possible.

Is it possible to configure a router in such a way, that 
it allows downloading anything at maximum speed -> but only after providing all users with a certain minimum network speed.

e.g if I have 5 users online, and 1 of them starts downloading a file, I would like to "reserve" 2Mbs for 4 users, and whatever bandwidth is left over, can be used by the 5th user to download stuff.
If no other users are online, i would like the only user who is online, to be able to use up all the bandwidth(not reserve 2Mbs for the other 4, just in case )

Comment: Yes, but this is heavily dependent on the brand / model of the Internet router used.  Please specify which router / firewall you have.

Comment: Shared connection and torrent traffic sounds to me like home networking which is off topic here...

Comment: @JFL The router is Inteno DG200A

Comment: This is a residential gateway, a consumer grade device that probably can't do this and is off-topic here (as well as home networking). You could add another router in front of this one (like a pfsense of VyOs) but this is a question for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your router specs -Interno DG200A- the answer is No.
The best you can do with that device is some CoS to assign voice, video or other traffic to queues and prioritize/mark as needed. Check starting page 40 on the [***User Guide***](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/875186/Inteno-Dg200-Series.html?page=39#manual).
For something more detailed or granular as you have requested the option would be to put another device in front of the router that can handle this or if you have some admin control over the users PC's, then check what specs does the OS provide for your needs.